# JavaScript: output of a function which returns a string outputs "undefined". Why that?

Tags: javascript, string

console.log in the function "getNameByDate" will produce "Ben" and "Tom".
But the other console.log outside of the function will produce "undefined". Why not the same output?

```
  let arr = [
    {
      databaseObject: { geburt: "24.01.2012", name: "Ben"}
    }, 
    {
      databaseObject: { geburt: "29.02.2012", name: "Tom"}
    }, 
  ];

  function getNameByDate(date) {
    jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {         
      if ( val.databaseObject.geburt == date ) {
        console.log (val.databaseObject.name);        
        return val.databaseObject.name;
      }
    });
  }

  let dates = ["24.01.2012", "29.02.2012"];

  jQuery.each( dates, function( i, val ) {
    console.log(getNameByDate(val));
  });
```

Comment: You are forgetting that `function (i, val) ...` is also a function and the return inside it belongs to `function (i, val) ...` not `getNameByDate()`. The function `getNameByDate()` returns nothing which in javascript is the same as `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Returning the result in the jQuery.each-loop was not correct. Instead we have to assign the result in that loop to a variable, break the loop by returning false and return the variable after the loop:

```
 let arr = [
    {
      databaseObject: { geburt: "24.01.2012", name: "Ben"}
    }, 
    {
      databaseObject: { geburt: "29.02.2012", name: "Tom"}
    }, 
  ];

  function getNameByDate(date) {
    var friendsName;
    jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {         
      if ( val.databaseObject.geburt == date ) {
        console.log (val.databaseObject.name);
        friendsName = val.databaseObject.name; 
        return false; // exit loop
      }
    });
    return friendsName;
  }

  let dates = ["24.01.2012", "29.02.2012"];

  jQuery.each( dates, function( i, val ) {
    console.log(getNameByDate(val));
  });
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also replace `jQuery.each()` with a for loop